# HTTP+MEAN: send resources before they are requested

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request, response

I have a MEAN stack application, as I understand it when a page is loaded the following occurs:

1. The Express app receives a request
2. The request is routed and an Express view is sent (in this case index.html)
3. Dependencies listed in index.html are requested - default stylesheet, angularJS, ect.
4. Static file server(s) respond with the requested items
5. AngularJS sets itself up in the DOM, binds all anchors, a list of dependencies is dynamically created, e.g. `<link ng-repeat="include in includes" rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{include.stylesheet}}">` will cause a bunch of HTTP requests to be prepared.
6. Requests are sent out for dependencies realized by AngularJS, this includes the AngularJS view (partial.html)
7. Static file server(s) respond with the requested items
8. partial.html requests all includes and dependencies (include1.hmtl)
9. Static file server(s) respond with the requested items
10. include1.html requests all dependencies (image.jpg)
11. Static file server(s) respond with image.jpg
12. The client has now received all necessary components and is rendered properly in-browser

This seems awfully tedious to me, requests have to go back and forth and travel much further than necessary. How can I make my app cache a list of dependencies for each page and respond to the initial request like "Yo, I know you're just asking for / and expecting a single file but I'm lookin' 'round knowing you'll be hassling me for more stuff soon as you got this. Let me send those shiznits for you now."?

Unless a better method exists dependencies that aren't sent to the client should then be loaded via HTTP request whilst those that are should be sitting in the browser cache and be ready to load locally.

Cheers for reading.

Comment: you can use html manifests to pre-cache or exclude from cache whatever resources you need/want.

Comment: @dandavis Not quite what I'm looking for. Though helpful with this method the first load would still involve a lot of back-and-forthing, resources would be cached client-side and I couldn't have a separate list for each page (as in root/#/home and root/#/article/12).

Comment: you can build the manifest dynamically and pass a path token to it if you want a per-page list. this would provide an opportunity to tie into other parts of your system, so it might not be much extra code to implement. it also provides a free bonus JS api to explicitly manage the resources client-side.